# What are steps necessary to deploy django application to make it live using apache server?

Tags: python, django

I am host my locally build django app into live server in Digital Ocean using public IP. My VM is debian based.

What i did is:

1. Copy my "attendance" project into /var/www/.
2. I created new conf file in: /etc/apache2/sites-available/attendance.conf. I enable it and disable 000-default.conf.

In attendance.conf I put code like:

<VirtualHost *:80>

```
ServerAdmin admin@143.244.134.97
ServerName 143.244.134.97
ServerAlias 143.244.134.97
DocumentRoot /var/www/attendance


ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

3. I enable apache 2 also.
4. When I go to the browser I view only the files. It is like:
   [image seen in browser][1]

Do I didn't edit properly for wsgi setup in apache2>(application.conf).

OR

What are the other possible solution to make my site live?

Comment: You can push your code to github and then use any hosting site like heroku,pythonanywhere, aws. there're many option just scroll through google search

Comment: I solved it in extra two steps. I added code in new conf file in sites-available directory. And in apache2.conf I just added pythonpath. Then it works.